# Difference between "nur mehr" and "nur noch"

Tags: difference

What is the difference between "nur mehr" and "nur noch"?

Example:

> Wir haben nur noch 3 Stunden.
>   Wir haben nur mehr 3 Stunden.

Is there any difference or does it mean exactly the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both versions are correct in different variations of standard German.

> Wir haben nur noch 3 Stunden.

is German German (the variation of standard German spoken in Germany) ("deutsches Deutsch"; "deutschländisches Deutsch" or "deutsches Hochdeutsch") while

> Wir haben nur mehr 3 Stunden.

is Austrian German (the variation of standard German spoken in Austria) ("österreichisches Deutsch" or "österreichisches Hochdeutsch").

Also in some Dialects (in Germany as well as in Austria) people use a word that is similar to "mehr" (not necessarily exact the same). In Dialects you find also that most words are pronounced different and that even grammar will change in some cases (Viennese Dialect for this example: "Mia hom nua mea drei Stund").

Note that the version with "noch" is also correct in Austrian German and that also many dialects use variations of "noch" (again Viennese Dialect for this example: "Mia hom nua no drei Stund").

Comment: @christian.s I edited your text. Can you live with it?

Comment: Ich schätze Kooperation zwar sehr, denke aber doch, dass diese Änderung so weitreichend war, dass sie besser eine eigene Antwort gewesen wäre.

Comment: Ich kenne nur "nur noch". Interessant zu hören, dass "nur mehr" in Õstereich üblich ist.

Comment: Ich würde das "nur mehr" nur ungern unseren österreichischen Freunden zur exklusiven Nutzung überlassen.

Answer (score 0):

"nur noch" bezeichnet eine qualitative, "nur mehr" eine quantitative Verminderung, das hat, so meine ich, nichts mit "österreichischem oder deutschem Deutsch" zu tun.

Comment: Kannst du das noch ausführlicher Schreiben und mit Quellen hinterlegen? Zumal beides ja auf eine Quantität herausläuft (nur noch/mehr drei Stück) …

Comment: In meiner Zeit in Österreich ist mir die ständige Verwendung von *nur mehr* sehr aufgefallen, und ich bin mir sicher, dass das in Bayern auch so ist. Seit ich nicht mehr in Wien wohne sondern in Berlin, höre und lese ich *nur mehr* nur mehr gelegentlich. Der letzte Satz war ein Beispiel für die typisch austrobavarische Verwendung, die anderswo eher antiquiert wirkt.

Comment: willkommen auf german.se! da dies hier kein forum ist und hier normalerweise keine anreden oder sonstiges in den posts stehen, sondern man direkt zur Sache kommt, habe ich die anrede wegeditiert.